# how many points are required to specify a unique fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, sampling

I am measuring some property of a material that depends on the rotation angle of the material. Let the property be $f(\theta)$ , where $\theta$ is the rotation angle. From physics, we know that $f(\theta)$ is a periodic function with a period of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, since our measurement process is slow and discrete, we can take only a few measurement data. Our goal is to express the function $f(\theta)$ as a Fourier series of 3 harmonics. My question is how many equally spaced data points are needed to specify a unique three harmonic Fourier series ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) states that, considering uniform sampling,
the sample rate must be at least twice the bandwidth of the signal. In your question, the 3rd harmonic has a period of $\frac {\pi}{6}$, which means your sampling period should be less than or equal to $\frac {\pi}{12}$.